# How to use a global module

Tags: javascript, flowtype

So I have

```
declare module "test" {
    declare export type running = number;
}
```

in a lib file, and I was wondering how to use the module and what it's really for.

If I try something like:

```
async function testMe (testing_stuff /* : test.running */) {
}
```

It doesn't know what `test` is.

But if I don't have it in a module I can just straight up use `running` e.g.

```
declare type running = number;
```

Then use it as:

```
async function testMe (testing_stuff /* : running */) {
}
```

So what is the use of module here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
/*:: import type { running } from "test"; */

async function testMe (testing_stuff /* : running */) {
}
```

to import the type from the module.